# MySQL check count

Tags: mysql

I defined a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `wms__aktion_successor` (
 `aktion_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `successor_aktion_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`aktion_id`,`successor_aktion_id`)
)
```

I am searching for two given `aktion_id` if they have the same `successor_aktion_id`. I know already, that they have only one entry each as `aktion_id`.

I thought about a solution with `ALL` or something like this, but I have no correct idea.

My initial idea was

```
SELECT count(*)=2 
FROM `wms__aktion_successor` 
WHERE 
  (
      (`aktion_id`=5 AND `successor_aktion_id`=6) 
       OR
      (`aktion_id`=13 AND `successor_aktion_id`=6)
  )
```

but then I have to know the `successor_aktion_id`.

Comment: how should the output look like?

Comment: @dobberph Have you looked at my example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
aktion_id | successor_aktion_id 
-------------------------------
1         | 5
2         | 5
5         | 6
8         | 6
```

If your result should look like this you should try it with a self join on successor_aktion_id

```
SELECT * FROM wms__aktion_successor a, wms__aktion_successor b
WHERE a.successor_aktion_id = b.successor_aktion_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect.
Thanks for the hint with the self-join:

```
SELECT count(*)=1 
FROM wms__aktion_successor a, wms__aktion_successor b
WHERE a.successor_aktion_id = b.successor_aktion_id 
AND a.aktion_id=5 
AND b.aktion_id=13
```

... is what I needed
Thanks a lot.